# Wait for BackgroundWorker to complete?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, backgroundworker

I have 2 async processes that *need* to be called one after the other (one is an XML creation `backgroundworker` and the other is a raring BW that uses the XML files created in the first process). The main reason for these threads is to stop the UI freezing and provide a status update by the way of a progress bar - as such a synchronous approach is not desirable/possible.

```
if (!CreateXMLBW.IsBusy)
{
CreateXMLBW.RunWorkerAsync("");
}
if (!CreateRarBW.IsBusy)
{
CreateRarBW.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

I cannot put the second BW inside the first's completion event as the processes can be used separately and as such if I just want to create the XML files I can do that.

I have tried using `AutoResetEvent` and `WaitOne` but this (for whatever reason) still doesn't work.

Are there any other ways I can wait for a BW to complete without freezing the main UI thread?

Comment: Why you don't create a new Worker that run these 2 worker synchronously ? and you run this new worker async

Comment: I like this idea but goes against DRY.

Comment: It's dry, you don't repeat the code as you reuse the 2 other workers. Anyway, the Task solution proposed below is far more elegant :)

Comment: Not possible if you want to report progress to a progress bar/update labels etc as that then becomes a cross threading call. But yes Task is a nice solution, it will take a while for me to get out of the of the BGW way of thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is exactly what `Task` was designed for. In your particular case your code might look like this:

```
public delegate void UpdateUI(int progress);

private void RunOneAfterAnotherAsync()
{
    Task<XmlElement> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<XmlElement>(CreateXMLBW);
    task.ContinueWith(CreateRarBW);
}

private XmlElement CreateXMLBW()
{
    // your code

    // progress
    progressBar1.Invoke((UpdateUI)UpdateProgressBar, new object[] {progressValue});

    // result
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    return doc.CreateElement("element");
}

private void CreateRarBW(Task<XmlElement> task)
{
    CreateRarBW(task.Result);
}

private void CreateRarBW(XmlElement arg)
{
    // your code
}

public void UpdateProgressBar(int value)
{
    this.progressBar1.Value = value;
}
```

`RunOneAfterAnotherAsync` is not blocking and your 2 methods run asynchronously one after another. `CreateRarBW` runs only if `CreateXMLBW` ends with no exception but you can change that by using additional arguments in `ContinueWith`.

You can do much more than this example shows - I encourage you to explore the [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class.

**EDIT**

I have extend the example a little bit to incorporate a result being passed from the first task into the second one. Also added UI progress example.

Comment: Can I report progress or similar to the progress bar from within a Task without a cross threading exception?

Comment: To report progress you need to call some delegate from within your task. If you want to update UI directly from task you must use `Control.Invoke`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want block UI till waiting for event (so I *suppose* you're gonna do something)
you can raise an event at the end of the `DoWork()`, and UI thread can recieve it.

If you're using 4.0 and can avoid of using BackgroundWorker, you can make use of [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) from TPL.

A *pseudocode* may look like this:

```
   Action action =(() => DoWorkMethod());
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action()).ContinueWith(()=>CallAfterComplete());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.aspx) like in this example:

```
class Program
{
    static XElement CreateXml()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return XElement.Parse(@"<FooBar>Hi!</FooBar>");
    }

    static void ProceedXml(XElement xml)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew<XElement>(CreateXml)
                    .ContinueWith(t => ProceedXml(t.Result));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UI can handle the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event on the first BW and invoke the second BW.

Comment: As per my question - "I cannot put the second BW inside the first's completion event as the processes can be used separately and as such if I just want to create the XML files I can do that." Meaning if I put it in the RunWorkerCompleted event it would always trigger, which I do not want.

Comment: @Myles Well, ok, but I assumed that your UI would know whether it wants to run the second BW or not.  I didn't mean you would _always_ run it.